# How to add onClick for buttons?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out why my app crashes when my AddThreeToTeamA button crashes my application upon clicking. I have addded my XML and my Java code.
I am following a tutorial however it obviously does not crash and I have tried several different solutions.
Any hint will be appreciated.

```
package com.themovingmonkey.courtcounter;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


        int score = 0;
        int scoreTeamA;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
        public void addThreeForTeamA() {
            scoreTeamA = score + 3;
            displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        }

        public void addTwoForTeamA() {
            scoreTeamA = score + 2;
            displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        }

        public void addOneForTeamA() {
            scoreTeamA = score + 1;
            displayForTeamA(scoreTeamA);
        }
        public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
            TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Team_A_Score);
            scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(scoreTeamA));
        }


    }
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text= "Team A"
      android:padding="4dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/Team_A_Score"/>
  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="3 Points"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
      />
  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="2 Points"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
      />
  <Button
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="1 Point"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have to post the logs for your crash!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods defined using the `android:onClick="someMethod"` attribute. Then they have to be public and should pass a `View` as the only parameter, Change your methods to:

```
public void someMethod(View view){

  //Everything else!

}
```

Your methods do not pass a `View` as the only parameter at all currently!

Comment: thanks a bunch! worked like a charm, happy holidays!

Comment: Hey @GreyLarkan why you have removed the acceptance of my answer? Is it not working???